# Remapping "Command + Arrow Key" to jump through the words of CamelCase expressions?

Tags: macos, keyboard, cursor

I often go through sentences word-by-word, using Command+Arrow Keys.

However, when there is a word in **camel case** (e.g. "AppleForumsQuestion.txt", in filenames or so), that won't work - Command+Arrow Keys only snaps to spaces.

Is there any (system-wide, ideally) way to make it move the cursor to the individual "words" of also camel-case expressions?

Comment: I don't know a way to specifically step through a CamelCase series of words, but if you set the Languages & Text -> Text -> Word Break option to "English (United States, Computer)" and the Languages & Text -> Region to United States (Computer), it will make a nice difference (i.e. it will step through thing like addSubview:anotherView) (BTW did you mean Option + Arrow, Command + Arrow will take you to the beginning or end of the line)

Answer (score 2):

⌃← and ⌃→ do that by default in many code editors like Xcode, TextMate, Sublime Text, and BBEdit. (If you have disabled the shortcuts for changing desktops.) You can change the shortcuts in TextMate by [overriding KeyBindings.dict](http://lri.me/keybindings.dict).

I have tried adding something like this to DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
"^\UF702" = moveSubWordLeft:; // control-left
"^\UF703" = moveSubWordRight:; // control-right
```

It doesn't work in other applications though. And ⌘← and ⌘→ can't even be reassigned in DefaultKeyBinding.dict.